# Filter only if variable condition is not undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my router:

```
reportRoutes.route('/:id').get(async (req, res) => {
    try{
        let id = req.params.id
        console.log(req.query)
        let team = req.query.team
        let league_acronym = req.query.league
        console.log('team',team)
        let regex = new RegExp( id, 'i')
        const report = await Report.find({ title: regex })
            .populate({path: 'like'})
            .populate({
                path: 'player',
                populate: [{ path: 'team' },
                {
                    path: 'team',
                    populate: {
                        path: 'league'
                    }
                }
            ]
            })

            if(league_acronym) {
                newReport = report.filter((v,i) => {
                    return v.player.team.league.acronym === league_acronym  && v.player.team.team_name === team
                })
                res.json(newReport)
            } else{
                res.json(report)
            }
    }  catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

I'm trying to setup a filter that goes through report and returns newReport.

The conditions that it will filter on are based on query string parameters.

Because query string parameters will not always be present, I need a way to filter on a condition, only if the condition exists. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for the respective conditions only if there is a value in `league_acronym` and `team`

```
newReport = report.filter(v => 
  (!league_acronym || v.player.team.league.acronym === league_acronym) 
  && (!team || v.player.team.team_name === team)
)
```

Comment: this code wont run if `league_acronym` is undefined, see `if(league_acronym) {}`

Comment: @JuniusL. oh, didn't notice that. That has to removed, obviously

Comment: @adiga can you modify your answer so that it will run with undefined, and I can accept it

Comment: @schoenbl this will work if `league_acronym ` is undefined or null or empty string etc